# How to increment "number" field for each owner(ForeignKey) in Django

Tags: python, django, model, numbers

Here is my model , I want to have a number for each address each owner. An owner can have multiple addresses

Like owner A might have address 1 address 2 ..
owner B also : address 1 address 2 ..

```
class Address(TimeStamp):
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owner_address')

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk:
        for owner in self.owner:
            self.number += 1
    return super(DeliveryAddress, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you want to just keep a serial order of addresses of one owner, you can think of it this way. You can extract the Address records for a single Owner and get a count of it. When creating a new Address record, take that count, add 1 to it and you have next number. Something like this,

```
current_address_count = Address.objects.filter(owner=<some-owner>).count()
Address.objects.create(number=current_address_count+1, owner)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    obj.number = obj.owner.owner_address.count()
    obj.save()
    return obj
```

I think we do not need to increment count as the address is already added in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , well, I need to increment it each time th user enter another address, if u're talking about the id , it's not my case , the id gets changed if th address was deleted, but th number field will save the order for me.

Comment: yes I said that we do not need to increment because when we called save method for super, the address is now added in db and when we count it our newly added address is also counted. And yeah I think you also need to find a way to update address numbers when one of the address is deleted.

Comment: Oh I see what u meant now, you're right. I 'll see how to deal with it.. thanks agaain !